In Excel, I use a dropdown list which populates cells. I have enabled multiple select in the ddlist, but now the cells do not populate?
I have a dropdown list on excel. When an item is selected it prepopulates cells using VLOOKUP from the table/dropdown list. Now I have modified the VBA to enable multiple selection in the dropdown list from the table, but the cells now don't populate the cells due to multiple selections.
How can I get the cells I need to populate when selecting multiple items? The items chosen will vary, and so will the cells.
I keep attempting at changing the formula, but cannot resolve this issue.

Welcome to SO. please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example . Also check out the tour, and help center

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
